# React.js Sorting asc and desc in same button

Tags: reactjs, sorting

hi i did a sorting function where i defined the default sort of my data.map is asc and in my button i change to desc so my question is how i can do both asc and desc on the button

```
function AvailableVet() {
const [vets, setVets] = useState([]);
const  [sortType,setSorted] = useState('asc');
const sorted = vets.sort((a,b)=>{
    const isReversed = (sortType ==='asc') ? 1 : -1;
    return isReversed * a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
})
const onSort = sortType =>{
    setSorted({sortType})
    
}

<React.Fragment>
        <div className='title'>
            <h5 style={{ marginBottom: '20px' }}>
                {vets.length} médicos vetenários disponíveis
            </h5>
             <Button  align='left' className='text-field' placeholder='Ordenar'   onClick={()=>onSort('desc')}  endIcon={<UnfoldMoreSharpIcon></UnfoldMoreSharpIcon>}>Ordenar</Button>
        </div>
        <div>
            {sorted.map((data) => (
                <ObterMedicos
                    key={data.user_id}
                    id={data.user_id}
                    name={data.name}
                    specialty={data.specialty}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    </React.Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this snippent.

```
const onSort = () => {
  const sortOrder = sortType === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
  setSorted(sortOrder);
}
```

and then don't need to pass argument to `onSort`

`onClick={onSort}`